# Counting Active connections in peewee ORM

Tags: python-2.7, peewee

I am using Python's peewee ORM with MYSQL. I want to list the active connections for the PooledDatabase. Is there any way to list..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean "active"? Active as in being "checked out" by a thread, or active as in "has a connection to the database"?

For the first, you would just do `pooled_db._in_use`.

For the second, it's a little trickier -- basically it will be the combination of `pooled_db._in_use` (a dict) and `pooled_db._connections` (a heap).

Comment: I mean, I set max_connections=10, i need to check used connections.

Comment: How to use `_in_use` & `_connections` to get used connections

Comment: You can check `_in_use` to see which connections are checked out currently, as I wrote in my comment. You can check `_connections` (the heap) for the list of open (but possibly stale) connections waiting to be checked out.